# Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection. at Protocol.end

Tags: mysql, nodejs, reactjs, express

Tengo un servicio con Express pero me manda el siguiente error:
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
at Protocol.end

Mi codigo es: 
App.js

```
        var createError = require('http-errors');
        var express = require('express');
        var path = require('path');
        var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
        var logger = require('morgan');
        var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
        var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
        var app = express();
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
        app.use(cookieParser());
        app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,UPDATE,OPTIONS');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
        next();
        });
        const mysql = require('mysql');
        const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: '192.0.0.127',
        port: 8080,
        user: 'user',
        password: '',
        database: '',
        insecureAuth: true
        });
        connection.connect(function (err) {
        (err) ? console.log('Error en la conexion') : console.log('Conectado');
        });
        require('./routes/html-routes')(app, connection);
```

html-routes.js

```
                const path = require("path");
            const mysql = require("mysql");
            const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
            const express = require("express");

            module.exports = function(app, connection) {
                router.get("/disponible", function(req, res) {
                    var tipo = req.query.tipo;
                    connection.query("call sp_disponible('" + tipo + "');", function(
                        err,
                        data
                    ) {
                        err ? res.send(err) : res.json({ disponible: data });
                    });
                });

                router.post("/distanciaTorton", function(req, res) {
                    var servicio = req.query.servicio;
                    connection.query(
                        "call sp_distanciaTorton('" + servicio + "');",
                        function(err, data) {
                            err ? res.send(err) : res.json({ distancia: data });
                        }
                    );
                });

                app.use("/tes/api", router);
            };
```

El error que me manda es:

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
at Protocol.end (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
at Socket. (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
                at Socket. (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
                at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
                at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
                at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
                at args.(anonymous function) (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/event-loop-inspector/index.js:138:29)
                at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
                at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
                Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
                at Protocol.end (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
                at Socket. (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
                at Socket. (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
                at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
                at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
                at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
                at args.(anonymous function) (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/event-loop-inspector/index.js:138:29)
                at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
                at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
                Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
                at Protocol.end (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
                at Socket. (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)
                at Socket. (/var/www/tescobedoBackEnd/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
                at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
                at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
                at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
                at args.(anonymous function) (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/event-loop-inspector/index.js:138:29)
                at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
                at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)

No se a que se debe este error, mi repositorio se encuentra en: https://github.com/GabrielaVillaAngeles/BackEndExpress